# CSV to HTML table using Javascript. Adding CSS class using a column in the CSV

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a JS that pulls data from a CSV and creates a HTML table. This is my current script. Its working fine but I would like to add functionality.

I want to not show the last column and use that data to set the CSS class of the row.

this is just me tinkering and learning so an explanation not just a solution would be amazing!

```js
function pullData() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var data = this.responseText;
      var lines = data.split(/\r?\n|\r/),
        output = [],
        i;
      for (i = 0; i < lines.length; i++)
        output.push(
          "<tr><td>" + lines[i].split(",").join("</td><td>") + "</tr></td>"
        );
      output =
        "<table><tr><th>One</th><th>Two</th><th>Three</th><th>Four</th><th>Five</th><th>Six</th><th>Seven</th><th>Colour</th></tr>" +
        output.join("") +
        "</table>";
      var div = document.getElementById("container");

      div.innerHTML = output;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "data.csv", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

it produces

[Table produced by JS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYwPY.png)

Answer (score 1):

One option is to split the data for each row into an array. Then use `pop()` to retrieve and remove the last element of the array which is the color. Then use that for the class name or inline style.

```js
const data = `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,red
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,blue
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,green
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,yellow
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,orange
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,pink`;

var lines = data.split(/\r?\n|\r/),
  output = [],
  i;
for (i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
  let columns = lines[i].split(",");
  output.push("<tr style='background-color:" + columns.pop() + "'><td>" + columns.join("</td><td>") + "</tr></td>");
}
output = "<table><tr><th>One</th><th>Two</th><th>Three</th><th>Four</th><th>Five</th><th>Six</th><th>Seven</th></tr>" +
  output.join("") +
  "</table>";
var div = document.getElementById("container");
div.innerHTML = output;
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```